# How to update notification content

Tags: android, notifications

I use a Library to get a music media metadata (mu, then I want to show it in notification
I tried this :

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(stream);
    OnNewMetadataListener ilistener = new OnNewMetadataListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNewHeaders(String stringUri, List<String> name, List<String> desc, List<String> br, List<String> genre, List<String> info) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onNewStreamTitle(String stringUri, final String streamTitle) {
            int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.black_overlay);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Teskies (Online Radio)")
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                    .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setContentText("Song :"+streamTitle);
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            NotificationManager manger = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            builder.setColor(color);
            assert manger != null;
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            manger.notify(0,notification);

        }
    };
    AudiostreamMetadataManager.getInstance()
            .setUri(uri)
            .setOnNewMetadataListener(ilistener)
            .setUserAgent(UserAgent.WINDOWS_MEDIA_PLAYER)
            .start();
```

It shows the current music information, but in the begin of the next music, the old music's title stays in notification it didn't update with new data.

Comment: Code seems to work here. Are you sure new metadata is received? Can you provide the streaming url?

Comment: @tim Yes ! here is the url : https://plaza.one/mp3 because I already did that in a TextView, but I want to did it using notification!

Comment: Still works. Maybe something else is conflicting with it? Wonky internet connection? Does it reconnect for example?

Comment: The music data works perfectly, but when the music changes, the new data of the new music didn't came up